# How to show images in a gridview after iterating over a list of Url's in asp.net MVC5?

Tags: asp.net, razor, foreach

I have the following code in my View.

```
@model MovieApp.Models.HomeIndexViewModel
@foreach (var item in Model.Movies)
{
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-4">
             <img src=item.posterPath id="picture1" class="img-responsive" />
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
}
```

I retrieve the image Url's on item.Posterpath as a string.

When I try to add my Url's on item.PosterPath as `<img src=item.posterPath id="picture1" class="img-responsive"/>`I can see that the item is not in scope.
My question is how i should iterate over my Model to stay in the scope and retrieve my paths?

Comment: have you tried `src="@item.posterPath"` ?

Comment: thanks. I don't know, how I could not see that. If you write your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried `src="@item.posterPath"` ?